# Regex to get SLD + TLD from domain string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function that takes a domain name as an argument but the domain must be in the format of `xxx.com`. e.g. `http://subdomain.example.com` must be passed into the function as `example.com`.

I have written the below regex but it's only returning the TLD (.com). I'm a bit of a newb with regex so can't really see where I've gone wrong... The first statement is to extract `http://` from `domain` and the second statement should extract any subdomain.

`var domain = req.query.domain.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '').replace(/^[^.]+\./g, '');`

Using the above regex, `http://example.com` becomes `com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to match the pattern directly than to match and remove its complement. I would use the pattern `/[^./]+\.[^./]+$/`. This matches two runs of non-special characters separated by a period at the end of the string.

```js
alert('http://subdomain.example.com'.match(/[^./]+\.[^./]+$/)[0]);
alert('http://example.com'.match(/[^./]+\.[^./]+$/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier answer is to use the `document.createElement` trick shown [here](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561)

To get the hostname and TLD, you'd simply write

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = req.query.domain;

var formattedDomain = link.hostname; //yay
```

Comment: This is Node, therefore `document` isn't available.

Comment: Would have been helpful to include that information.